# How to turn while loops into functions

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop, simulation

I have created a simulation where a program moves along a sequence. When it moves to an element in the sequence it changes that element from a 0 to a 1, and changes the element it just left from a 1 to a zero. It can only start, move to the next element, leave the sequence if a randomly generated number is less than each elements associated score.

Here is the code for it:

```
import random
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as plt
random.seed(5)
f = random.randint(0,3)
m = random.randint(0,3)
s = random.randint(0,3)

seq = [0.2]*s + [0.5]*m + [0.8]*f
random.shuffle(seq)
seq = [0.1] + seq
seq = seq + [0.1]
state = [0]*len(seq)


record = []
count = 0
pool = 10

while count < len(seq)+1:
    if count == 0 and random.random() < seq[count]:
        print("START")
        print("random is less than", seq[count])
        state[count]+=1
        pool-=1
        print(state)
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 1
    elif count == 0 and random.random() > seq[count]:
        print("DOES NOT START")
        print("random is greater than", seq[count])
        state[count]+=0
        pool-=0
        print(state)
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 0
    elif count > 0 and count <= len(seq)-1 and random.random() < seq[count]:
        print("DOES MOVE")
        print("random is less than", seq[count])
        state[count]+=1
        state[count-1]-=1
        print(state)
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 1
    elif count > 0  and count < len(seq)-1 and random.random() > seq[count]:
        print("DOES NOT MOVE")
        print("random is greater than", seq[count])
        state[count]+=0
        state[count-1]-=0
        print(state)
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 0
    elif count == len(seq) and random.random() < seq[count-1]:
        print("END")
        print("random is less than", seq[count-1])
        state[count-1]+= -1
        pool+=1
        print(state)
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 1
    elif count == len(seq) and random.random() > seq[count-1]:
        print("DOES NOT END")
        print("random greater than", seq[count-1])
        state[count-1]-= 0
        pool+=0
        print(state)
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 0
    print("count is: ", count)
```

How can I turn the simulation into a function so I can run multiple simulations at once without having to copy the whole simulation code?

I have looked at other stackoverflow answers and these have not helped me much. I am quite new to coding so I dont know if this is a trivial thing to do? any feedback/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the function input would be a sequence and the output would be a list of lists 'record' outling how the program moves through the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the operation under a function, and pass in the inputs

```
import random
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as plt
random.seed(5)

def simulation(s,m,f):
    seq = [0.2] * s + [0.5] * m + [0.8] * f
    random.shuffle(seq)
    seq = [0.1] + seq
    seq = seq + [0.1]
    state = [0] * len(seq)

    record = []
    count = 0
    pool = 10
    while count < len(seq)+1:
        if count == 0 and random.random() < seq[count]:
            print("START")
            print("random is less than", seq[count])
            state[count]+=1
            pool-=1
            print(state)
            record.append(state.copy())
            count += 1
        elif count == 0 and random.random() > seq[count]:
            print("DOES NOT START")
            print("random is greater than", seq[count])
            state[count]+=0
            pool-=0
            print(state)
            record.append(state.copy())
            count += 0
        elif count > 0 and count <= len(seq)-1 and random.random() < seq[count]:
            print("DOES MOVE")
            print("random is less than", seq[count])
            state[count]+=1
            state[count-1]-=1
            print(state)
            record.append(state.copy())
            count += 1
        elif count > 0  and count < len(seq)-1 and random.random() > seq[count]:
            print("DOES NOT MOVE")
            print("random is greater than", seq[count])
            state[count]+=0
            state[count-1]-=0
            print(state)
            record.append(state.copy())
            count += 0
        elif count == len(seq) and random.random() < seq[count-1]:
            print("END")
            print("random is less than", seq[count-1])
            state[count-1]+= -1
            pool+=1
            print(state)
            record.append(state.copy())
            count += 1
        elif count == len(seq) and random.random() > seq[count-1]:
            print("DOES NOT END")
            print("random greater than", seq[count-1])
            state[count-1]-= 0
            pool+=0
            print(state)
            record.append(state.copy())
            count += 0
        print("count is: ", count)
        
f = random.randint(0,3)
m = random.randint(0,3)
s = random.randint(0,3)

simulation(f,m,s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A python function requires inputs and will return something. For instance:

```
def function_name(x):

    return x**2
```

This function takes a number x and will give it's squared value, so what I advise you to do is:

-Think of the inputs you want (these will be the values required for your simulation)

-What you want your function to give you. If it's counts then do `return counts`

To run the function just call it to a variable:

```
result = function_name(2)
```

This `result` will be 4 in the example I have shown